# Problems in handling Back Button in Ionic 4

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

When I built and ran my app on android, I realized that the hardware back button is not working. 
I Have the main page, which has two children, a home and a favorite page, where the home page is the default page. 
If I am at the Favourites page and I click the back button, it takes me to the home page, but from the home page, if I click the back button, it shows a white screen and restarts the app after few seconds.
I would only be able to close the app if I click it three times.
I am using ionic 4, Angular 8.

Here is how my app route looks like:

```
  { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/main/main.module#MainPageModule' },
  { path: 'search', loadChildren: 
  './pages/search/search.module#SearchPageModule' },
  { path: 'catalog-view', loadChildren: './pages/cat-view/cat- 
  view.module#CatViewPageModule' },
```

and here is what my main module looks like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainPage,
    children: [
     { path: 'home', loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
      { path: 'favorites', loadChildren: 
     '../favorites/favorites.module#FavoritesPageModule' },
       ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
       redirectTo: '/main/home'
       }
   ];
```

I tried to add this functionality at the homePage, then the Main, and even the Appcompomponent, but nothing works:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=>{
      navigator['app'].exitApp();
  });
}

 ionViewWillLeave(){
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working, the problem was very silly.
I had to update my packages to the latest version, especially the @ionic-native/core.
and in my  home.ts i just simply do this:

```
ngOnInit(){
     this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
     this.platform.backButton.unsubscribe();
     navigator['app'].exitApp();
   })
)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have the following code in my home page, het registers a different function to the back button while on the home page. and then deregister it again as soon as it leaves.

```
private isToastShown: boolean = false;

ionViewDidEnter(){
        /* When on home page the back button should confirm before exiting */
        this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
            if (!this.isToastShown) {
                this.presentConfirm();
            } else {
                navigator['app'].exitApp();
            }
        }, 0);
    }

    ionViewWillLeave() {
        /* Reset back button to pop pages when pressed */
        this.aPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
            if (this.aNavController.canGoBack()) {
                this.aNavController.pop();
            }
        });
    }

    private presentConfirm(): void {
        this.isToastShown = true;

        let lToast = this.aToastController.create({
            message: "Press back again to exit"
        });

        lToast.present().then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                lToast.dismiss();
                this.isToastShown = false;
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am using ionic 4 though, the registerBackButton, and the exitApp() do not exist in that version

Comment: Edit answer with ionic 4, function unsure how to navigate back since you no longer push pages but navigate to them, so you might need to set where your back button goes on every page`s IonViewDidEnter

Comment: with ionic 4 it automatically navigates back to the home page when clicking the back button. The problem however is in the home page. When I click back on the home page it shows a white screen and then the app restarts.